# Get System operative information with Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Somebody know how can I get, for example: windows user name, computer name..etc, with a postgres query or function?

Thanks!!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the 2-minute [tour]. 
Moreover, open [Help] and read at least [ask]. 
Then you know what we expect from questioners: showing us the code on 
where you stuck solving the task by yourself and explaining why you fail to complete the task. Sorry, but Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service.

Answer (score 0):

Easy with:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE client_addr = inet_client_addr();
```